# Move files to parent directory if their extension matches the sub-directory extension

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am looking for a batch script which will move files from a sub-directory to its parent if their extension matches the sub-directory extension.

Examples:

- Move any `.txt` file from `directory parent\files.txt\`

  `"parent\files.txt\test.txt"` will become `"parent\test.txt"`

---

- Move any `.zip` file from `directory parent\files.zip\`

  `"parent\files.zip\test.zip"` will become `"parent\test.zip"`

I want only to `move` the file if its extension is the same as that of its sub-directory name. The sub-directory and any other content has to be left alone.

This is what I have now, but it only removes my files:

```
@echo off
md temp
set view=
if "%view%"=="1" @echo on
color 72
mode con cols=30 lines=8
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p location_with_dirs=location: 
echo:
type nul> ".\temp\folderlist.txt"
FOR /D %%G IN ("%location_with_dirs%\*") DO (
    echo process file:
    echo %%G
    choice
    if "%errorlevel%"=="1" echo %%G >> ".\temp\folderlist.txt"
    cls
)
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (".\temp\folderlist.txt") DO (
    for %%F in (%%G\*.*) do move /Y %%F "%location_with_dirs%\"
    rd %%G
)
del /f /q ".\temp\folderlist\*.txt"
```

Comment: To be clear, are you wanting to remove every `.ext` file from `foldername.ext\ ` And when you say `remove`, do you mean `delete`, or `move`? _And what's stopping you opening `foldername.ext\ `in Windows Explorer, searching/selecting by `.ext` extension and pressing delete?_

Comment: No there isn't, the technique is the same regardless of number of files in the directory! _Open the directory, type *.ext into the search box, select all and copy or move or delete them according to your preference_

Comment: Wrong; you said you were moving them to their parent directory, in that scenario, there is no overhead, _only file pointers are adjusted, nothing is actually moved_, because the drive letter remains the same.

Comment: just edited. maybe a little more clear now?

Comment: @Compo: OP is asking about a batch file solution, not an Explorer solution.

Comment: @Marnix0810, please don't try to edit and completely change my answer by adding all of your code to it, it is unnecessary and not pertinent to the question asked. I have additionally removed the unnecessary code from your question too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there will be many ways of achieving this, here's one:

```bat
@CD /D "Parent" 2>Nul || Exit /B
@For /D %%A In (*) Do @If /I Not "%%~xA"=="" Move /-Y "%%A\*%%~xA">Nul
```

*Just change `Parent` on line `1` to the full or relative path of your parent directory.*

Just as a courtesy, heres a version which hopefully improves on the more important part of your provided code, *(it ignores the progress bar and color stuff)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
:AskDir
Set "dir_with_files="
Set /P "dir_with_files=location: "
If "%dir_with_files%"=="" GoTo AskDir
If "%dir_with_files:~-1%"=="\" Set "dir_with_files=%dir_with_files:~,-1%"
If Not Exist "%dir_with_files%\" GoTo :AskDir
Set "_rand=%dir_with_files%\%random%.organizer.lock.txt"
Type Nul>"%_rand%" 2>Nul && (Del "%_rand%") || GoTo :AskDir
If "%dir_with_files:~-1%"==":" Set "dir_with_files=%dir_with_files%\"
CD /D "%dir_with_files%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
For /D %%A In (*) Do If /I Not "%%~xA"=="" Move /-Y "%%A\*%%~xA">Nul 2>&1
Exit /B.
```

Comment: that is what i wanted. but it would be perfect if it is also usable on a root directory.

Comment: I have removed my 'root directory' statement, and would just like to clarify. You can use a root directory as the parent directory, the potential issue being with the Windows system root directory, which is not usually available unless the script is being run As administrator.